# Spring Cloud Stream embedded header format (Kafka)

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm using **Spring Cloud Stream** binder from the Edgware release to send Kafka messages. I'm also using **Spring Sleuth** with **Zipkin**.

Spring embeds headers into the Kafka message using a custom class `EmbeddedHeaderUtils`. This causes a problem for some non-Spring consumers of the message who would have to deal with this custom decoding.

*My Question:* Is there a way to configure Spring with a custom encoder/decoder for message headers (e.g. plain JSON)? Or possibly use Kafka Headers?

Ideally any custom implementation needs to work with Spring Sleuth and Zipkin.

I've been having a look at the latest Finchley release to see if Kafka headers will be supported but not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded headers are not pluggable, but you can disable them with `...producer.header-mode=raw`.

With Ditmars (1.3.x) you can use the kafka11 artifact, which supports native headers - you have to override a bunch of dependencies (kafka-clients, SK, SIK and kafka itself if you are using the `KafkaEmbedded` broker for testing. See [the relesae notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-starters/releases/tag/vDitmars.SR2)).

There's [a discussion on Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream?at=5a42e02ce43a7a150cabb613) about overriding the versions.

spring-kafka 1.3.x natively uses 0.11 but 1.3.1 and higher (1.3.2 is current) also supports the 1.0.0 client.

Elmhurst (2.0) - currently in milestones - uses SK 2.1.0 which natively uses 1.0.0 kafka.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Do you know if the Spring Sleuth / Zipkin implementation will still work when using the Kafka native headers in this way?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't, as long as you override all the necessary versions explicitly for both producers and consumers.